# targeting iOS5 - will it work on iOS6 also?

Tags: ios

Hello I am beginner with these things and would appreciate nice explanations
that would dismiss my doubts.

If I target my app for iOS 5 -- does it mean users who have iOS 6 and iOS 7 can
also use it? Anything I should watch out for?

Comment: It should be you need to test your app thoroughly on devices running the newer versions of iOS, especially iOS 7. But the better question is why are you targeting only iOS 5? iOS 7 will be out very soon and over 90% of users are on iOS 6. Supporting iOS 5 will soon be quite pointless.

Comment: @rmaddy: Maybe my terminology is not quite correct as I mentioned I am new to these things. It is not my goal that my application is available *only* for iOS5 users. Ideally I want *both* users of iOS5 and iOS6 to be able to use it, and later maybe also users of iOS7. Should I have used term targetting iOS5 and iOS6 instead?

Comment: @rmaddy, iPad 1 is stuck on iOS 5 (can't upgrade to iOS 6).

Comment: @MarcusAdams Yes it is. How is that relevant? I have a 1st gen iPod touch stuck on iOS 3.1.3. Old hardware can't be updated. As a developer, do you want to spend your time writing apps for what most people have (newer hardware running new versions) or do you want to spend a lot of effort trying to support a tiny fraction of users using older stuff?

Comment: @user2568508 At the end of this year, millions and millions of new iOS devices with iOS 7 will be sold over the holidays. By then over 95% of active iOS devices will be running iOS 7 or iOS 6. Think about that as you spend the next few months writing a new app. Supporting iOS 5 is wasted effort for virtually no gain. If you want your app to make money or reach the largest audience, target what they will be using - iOS 6 and iOS 7.

Comment: @rmaddy: I thought about supporting iOS5 and iOS6 because: I thought there maybe more users using iOS5 in my country than somewhere else on the average for example, plus I thought there are not much differences between iOS5 and iOS6, so writing my app such that it is available on *both* iOS-es (5 and 6) is not much work -- was I wrong?

Comment: @rmaddy, I'm not going to arbitrarily exclude iOS 5 users if I'm not using any features exclusive to iOS 6+. With that said, all my apps in the store require iOS 6+. :) I don't lose much sleep over it.

Comment: @user2568508 There are a huge number of new features in iOS 6 over iOS 5. Look at the API diffs in the iOS documentation. In the end though, it's up to you to decide how best to support your expected customers.

Comment: @rmaddy: thanks for your comments first. Anyway, so far I think I am missing something simple: we said initially even if I write an app that is suitable for iOS5 -- then iOS6 users shall also be able to use it right? (Then it does not mean I am losing users with iOS6, isn't it?)

Comment: possible duplicate of your own (and many other of your questions) [iOS version pros and cons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18204244/ios-version-pros-and-cons). Please don't keep asking the same questions because the originals are being closed or put on hold. Edit the original question to make it better.

Comment: @rmaddy Please spend a lot of effort for the tiny fraction of people that have older stuff, at least, when you're talking about my iPad 1 (ya know, the one that's only a couple of years old and in perfect working order)! Or slip me $400, I'd be happy with that too.

Answer (score 3):

There are two primary settings used for your targeting your builds:

Base SDK & Deployment Target.

The Base SDK = What are the latest features I want available in this app?

The Deployment Target = What is the earliest OS I want to be able to run this app?

So, if you have both of these set to iOS 6, the user must have iOS 6 to install or run the app.

If you have a Deployment Target of iOS 5.0 and a Base SDK of 6.0 that means it'll install and run in iOS 5.0, but you need to be careful to branch your code and not use any iOS 6.0 features if the user is running on an iOS 5.0 device.

Comment: Thanks for bringing up two settings: base SDK & Deployment target. I didn't know there were these two settings. Nabeel, so, if I want to write my application such that both users of iOS5 and iOS6 could use it, I should follow your advice in the last paragraph?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the target is the minimum version version that the app can run on. That doesn't mean that the app will work properly on newer versions and you really need to test to be sure. If you're creating a new app think carefully about which older versions to support.

Comment: Dear Wain, as I asked in the question and people replied my app (say built using Xcode 4.6 and target 5.0) can run on iOS7. But I guess this will give the app iOS6 look? Can't I change it later? (e.g., after I submit the app?). Thanks.

Comment: You should do some testing on iOS 7 too see what happens / works. You can change in the future with an app update.

Answer (score 0):

If you target your Application for a lower iOS version, anyone with the version number you target AND HIGHER and access the application. Anyone LOWER than the one you target will not be able to download and use the application.

Answer (score 0):

Everything will work fine, however there are certain features that are only available in iOS6 and iOS7 such as UICollectionView is only available in iOS6 and above. Fortunately you can test the different OS's in the simulator, it will make you life easier and you will be able to see if your application breaks running a different OS.